# Files corrupted after Defragmentation

Tags: compression, defragment, file-corruption

This is my first post in this forum.

**The Problem:**

Today, I decided to defragment and optimise my 2TB external Hard Disk using Auslogics Defragmenter. Now, a little background here. The partition that I defragmented was a 1.8TB partition encrypted by VeraCrypt, a fork of TrueCrypt. After the defragmentation was completed, I found that several files have been corrupted. The files in which I could detect the corruption were all compressed files, compressed using Windows 10's default compression. I opened the files up in WinHex and I saw a curious thing: The end of all these corrupted files had a block of "DF DF DF" sequence. I am attaching a screenshot to illustrate the matter. [Here is the Screenshot of the Problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iKRq.png)

Please note that, though the picture shows it's an arc file, it was still compressed by Windows compression. The curious thing is that, even though the files had those DF chunks, a cursory HEX Search of the raw data hard drive did not yield any such sequence. Of course, I didn't have the time to scan the whole 2TB HDD for those sequences.

Could you tell me if there is any way to possibly solve the problem? I already ran a Data Recovery Software but to no avail. I am absolutely frantic, and would be grateful if you could kindly help me solve the problem.

Comment: defraggers have the potential to corrupt your data, that's why the documentation says to back-up first.

Comment: I have been using Auslogics for about seven years now. This is the first time something of this magnitude has happened.

Comment: Is there any way to undo the damage?

Comment: check with Auslogics Defragmenter manual if the tool provides any facilities to perform an `undo`. No common tools could help you (There is no standard on how to move files while defragmenting, there are a lot of different strategies...)

Comment: Chances are that the issue was there before, and the defragging has made it much larger. Defragging itself is not the risky part (after all, it's read-write-repeat); but if anything in the file system it slightly off before, the issues get magnified.

Comment: I was scouring the internet for any sort of clue and I have found this: http://www.farmanager.com/enforum/viewtopic.php?t=318. Is the DF chunk some sort of compression voodoo?

Comment: Without data to compare to, there really is, not much you can do.

Comment: I would warn anyone reading this, it's not a good idea to run any type of tool on an encrypted drive/partition since the contents will just look like garbage.

Comment: Well, the partition is completely encrypted. So, when I mount it and defrag it, it is defragged like a normal hard disk. It's not an encrypted container I am defragging.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because you have installed some programs while defragmenting this happened with me. Don't use your pc while defragmenting.